# rename the name of images using unix command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have a lot of images (.png) file. Now i want to rename the images.Images name are like that

```
finalnfootok1.png
finalnodiabooks15.png
finalnpluggd17.png
```

and now i want to cut the letters "finaln" from the fast and the numbers from the last of the images.how can i use the ubuntu command to rename the images name.

Is there any way to rename the images using regex in the command line of ubuntu.I try with the rename command but i am not strong in using for loop and how to cut the letters from the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one off, you can use "sed" to strip the filenames:

```
for f in finaln*
do
    mv $f `echo $f | sed -e 's/finaln//g' -e 's/[0-9]*.png/.png/g'`
done
```

the backticks (`) execute the enclosed command `echo filename | sed...`  The first sed expression replaces `finaln` with nothing. The second sed expression replaces digits before ".png" with nothing. You could probably combine these into a single sed, but it's easier to understand as 2 expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I have to remove the numbers from the images file name.

Comment: Edited to add a 2nd sed expression that replaces numbers before .png with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep finaln | awk '{print $1,$1}' | sed s/finaln// | awk '{print $2,$1}' | xargs -n 2 mv
```